# Correct way to listen for HTTP and HTTPS in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to serve both HTTP and HTTPS in my NodeJS-app. It's for an internal applcaition where some visitors cannot support HTTPS.

Is this the simple correct way, or should it be 2 independent NodeJS app's?

```
http.createServer(app).listen(80, function () {
    console.log('My insecure site');
});

https.createServer(options, app).listen(443, function () {
    console.log('My sdecure site');
});
```

Comment: This is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way. You can do a little more optimisation as both HTTP and HTTPS server do the same thing. Create a function called `register` that will configure middleware and routes. Then just invoke it for both HTTP and HTTPS.

```
var register = function (app) {
    // config middleware
    app.configure({

    });

    // config routes
    app.get(...);
};

var http = express.createServer();
register(http);
http.listen(80);

var https = express.createServer();
register(https);
https.listen(443);
```